# Combining two time series with normalization

Tags: time-series, normalization, standardization

I have two sets of time series data with different distributions. Basically, one is count of likes for a post and the other one is the likes on the corresponding comments. It looks like this
[image: Distribution of likes and comments vs time]

Now, I need to put them into a single time series with proper scaling to make them comparable. I tried to scale the mean of the comments like distribution to the mean of the like distribution of the posts, but this approach scales up the min values of comments to way more than those of the posts.

I need to neutralize the effect of two things here:

1. The users who interact with these posts and comments has increased substantially over time.
2. I assume that comments tend to get fewer likes than posts

What should be a standard approach to normalizing these distributions to represent them in a single time series?

**EDIT** Since I have timestamps of both posts and comments, I can form a single time series by putting the data points at appropriate time intervals.  When I directly normalize the values, the comment like score becomes negligible. The scaling mean method makes the comment like values way higher than a typical like value.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. If you have data on likes of posts and their corresponding comments,wouldn't it make more sense to look at a scatter plot where the x-axis is the number of likes on the post and the y-axis is the number of likes on the comments? Also, I I don't understand why you want to neutralize point number 1? Are you trying to neutralize the effect of the fact of more people looking at the posts/comments as things have gotten more popular?

Comment: @roundsquare Yes. I am trying to neutralize the effect of increased user engagement with time. Basically, there should a normalization for this and then one to make both the distributions comparable.

Comment: What other information do you have access to? In particular, do you have access to the number of users engaging with the system in a given month or anything which would allow you to count/identify users? This could be very useful in controlling for point 1..

Comment: @roundsquare: Yes! That would have been really helpful. But sadly, count of users engaging with the community is not available. All we know is that the use base increases with time (safe to assume linearly)

Answer (score 1):

One option to get both measures in the same figure and make them comparable would be to plot both measures with their own, independent, y-axes as demonstrated in this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6143251/5703457.

As for neutralizing the evident increase in number of posts/likes over time, that's a difficult one. I would suggest normalizing the measures (value-mean / standard deviation) separately for the periods before and after the increase that happens between januari and april 2015.

Answer (score 0):

How about you plot likes on comments as a percent of likes on post? This would allow you to see their relative trend over time. In addition, I think it would essentially meet your requirements because:

1. Since comments on both increase, this would allow you to see the relationship between the two without worrying too much about how many users there were.
2. Scale wouldn't be a big deal since you can just scale your y-axis and look at the trend line.